# localhost:5000 is not loading my server!! Help needed

Tags: node.js, server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am learning node and was creating a server using Traversy media video on node . Now before this I made a server using w3schools documentation and it worked . But us not working using Traversy Media's way.

The callback in the .listen is working but in browser it says 'Problem loading page'.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req , res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
});

const PORT =5000;

server.listen(PORT , () => console.log(`server running at ${PORT}`));
```

browser keeps loading but never stops loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Read the documentation of how to create a server that will help you immensly.

```
const server = http.createServer((req , res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
});
```

In this case you are just printing the `req.url` without actually returning any `response` to the browser.

A proper hello world example will be:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Didn't get the concept then. Thanks , now I get what it is. Btw any recommended documentation for node.js .

Comment: If you are starting nodejs i think you should check out `https://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers` it has some interactive (easy->tough) tutorials. But your best bet is making things and checking nodejs official documents.